# add and use Shieldplugin to elasticsearch transportClient in Scala

Tags: scala, plugins, elasticsearch

How can i add the `Shieldplugin` to the `elasticsearch transportClient.addPlugin` in Scala?

In Java works with:

```
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder()
    .addPlugin(ShieldPlugin.class)
```

Comment: What is you problem specifically? Similar code should work in scala. The only thing to note is that `ShieldPlugin.class` should be written as `classOf[ShieldPlugin]` in scala

Comment: Thanks for Info, in my Code has `classOf[ShieldPlugin]` no effect (type missmatch).
The reason for this was the Import of the wrong Version of Shield.
Old 1.3.3 New 2.2.0